# How do I get fluent in Python?

Tags: python

Once you have learned the basic commands in Python, you are often able to solve most programming problem you face. But the way in which this is done is not really *Python-ic*. 
What is common is to use the classical c++ or Java mentality to solve problems. But Python is more than that. It has functional programming incorporated; many libraries available; object oriented, and its own ways. **In short there are often better, shorter, faster, more elegant ways to the same thing.**

It is a little bit like learning a new language. First you learn the words and the grammar, but then you need to get fluent.

Once you have learned the language, how do you get fluent in Python? How have *you* done it?  What books mostly helped?

Comment: Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Practice what?  What does that mean?

Comment: surprised that this question hasn't been closed by the SO community :)

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do XD

Comment: @MarkRansom you can practice 10 years and still be using the odd Java-style of programming.

Answer (score 11):

Read other people's code.  Write some of your own code.  Repeat for a year or two.

Study the Python documentation and learn the built-in modules.

Read Python in a Nutshell.

Subscribe your RSS reader to the Python tag on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

Have you read the [Python Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007973)? It's a pretty good source for Pythonic.

Plus you'll find [much more from Alex Martelli on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a95810%20[python]&tab=votes).

Answer (score 7):

I can tell you what I've done.

1. [Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)
2. Bookmark SO with the python keyword.
3. Read other's *good* python code.
4. [The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/)

That order is probably good, too. This is where things get fun.

Comment: Hello, and thanks. Does SO stand for stackoverflow? "3. Read other's good python code." any other source except the ones being proposed in the other answer?

Comment: +10 (if I could) for David Goodger's "Idiomatic Python" ref!  I've never read it before, but it is full of gems - learn these and Pythonic your code will become.  (Yes, SO is "stackoverflow".)

Comment: I know a very pythonic python programmers and very C++ python programmers. "Good" was a poor choice to express for the former!

Answer (score 5):

More Pythonic? Start with a simple import.

```
import this
```

And add practice.

Answer (score 3):

The same way you get fluent in any language - program a lot.

I'd recommend working on a project (hopefully something you'll actually use later). While working on the project, every time you need some basic piece of functionality, try writing it yourself, and **then** checking online how other people did it.

This both lets you learn how to actually get stuff done in Python, but will also allow you to see what are the "Pythonic" counterparts to common coding cases.

Answer (score 3):

There are some Python textbooks that not only teach you the language, they teach you the philosophy of the language (why it is the way it is) and teach you common idioms.  I learned from the book [Learning Python](http://www.rmi.net/~lutz/about-lp4e.html) by [Mark Lutz](http://www.rmi.net/~lutz/) and I recommend it.

If you already know the basics of the language, you can Google search for "Python idioms" and you will find some gems.  Here are a few:

http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/doanddont.html

http://jaynes.colorado.edu/PythonIdioms.html

If you read some good Python code and get a feel for why it was written the way it was, you can learn some cool things.  Here is a recent [discussion of modules worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490190/python-modules-most-worthwhile-reading) to improve your Pythonic coding skills.

Good luck!

EDIT: Oh, I should add: +1 for [Python Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007973) and Alex Martelli.  I didn't mention these because Jon-Eric already did.

Answer (score 2):

I guess becoming fluent in any programming language is the same as becoming fluent in a spoken/written language. You do that by speaking and listening to the language, a lot.

So my advice is to do some projects using python, and you will soon become fluent in it. You can complement this by reading other people's code who are more experienced in the language to see how they solve certain problems.

Answer (score 2):

Read existing projects known for technical excelence.

Some of the ones I'd recommend are:

- [Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django)
- [SQLAlchemy](http://svn.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/)
- Python's [`/lib/json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)
- Python's `/lib/test`
- Visit http://pythonsource.com/ for many other modules written in Python.